# Is there a way to check whether the entity manager has attached objects?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm working with EclipseLink and need to know whether there are attached objects before I call flush.

Comment: Why? Call flush(), an it won't do anything if there's nothing to do.

Comment: Have you tried entityManager.getDelegate()? Check the type & the methods of the returned object, may be you will find something.

Comment: @JBNizet I can imagine a use case when you wouldn't do that, although I don't think this is a good solution: you have an EJB service1 that updates an entity depending on a complicated business logic and you as a programmer do not have access to that code. And then, in your service2 you want to see if service1 is trying to update something, in order to inject some additional logic.

Comment: There are some complex scenarios which requires calling flush. But I want to verify that the amount of attached objects are equal to my local scope knowledge and identify situations where I'm detaching objects which aren't mine (where added by other places logic and will probably break if someone will try to update them after my code).